# "Standard" way of representing CRUD permissions for many heterogenous objects

Tags: performance, database-design, permissions, crud

The question deals with permissions in a standard wiki-style app. Suppose that we have a Confluence-like web application with thousands of users. Since we're "enterprise", we need fine-grained access control.

We need to be able to say "this user or this group of users" has access to this page|space (space is a collection of pages, essentially). Or, "ONLY this user or this...". Naturally, permissions are inherited - if one cannot view a page, one cannot view it's descendants and vice versa.

What I would also like is to be able to reasonably quickly answer the following question: "Can this particular user view this and that page"? Say, I need to render a hundred internal links to other pages, but only render them if the user can actually view them.

Quite honestly, I don't see a trivial way to implement even the first paragraph, let alone the second one. However, this problem is surely one that many developers encounter, and so my question is: what is the "standard" way of implementing access control systems like the one above, if there is one? It simply seems such a ubiquitous issue that I somehow think there MUST be proven, robust solutions that everyone knows, but I have no idea where to start designing one.

A many-to-many between pages and users would lead to a combinatorial explosion (not to mention you would need to recalculate inherited permissions every time either page tree or permissions change). Direct database queries (at least SQL ones, not too familiar with NoSQL) would probably be too slow. Kinda out of ideas here.

Comment: There is no combinatorial explosion...  You seem mainly worried of performance issues, let me just reassure you that a RDBMS (especially if the database is well designed) is possibly the *most efficient* solution to such problems. -- That said, you are asking for *a complete and quite non trivial design*, so I'd be inclined to suggest that you either drop this question and ask smaller questions focused to one step at a time (and more detailed as to what you have at hand than the above: you should show your code/schemas); or, you put a reasonable bounty on this question...